# Programmatically getting per-process disk io statistics on Windows?

Tags: c++, windows, performance, disk

I would like to display a list of processes (Windows, C++) and how much they are reading and writing from the disk in KB/sec.

The Resource Monitor of Windows 7 has the ability so I should be able to do the same.

However I have unable to find a relevant API-call or find anything in the perfmon counters. Could anyone point me in the direction?

Comment: I think event tracing (ETW) is the only way to go... But decent ETW examples are very scarce..

Answer (score 13, accepted):

You can call [GetProcessIoCounters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683218(VS.85).aspx) to get overall disk I/O data per process - you'll need to keep track of deltas and converting to time-based rate yourself.

This API will tell you total number of I/O operations as well as total bytes.

Comment: If that doesn't get you there, you might have to dig around and write a WMI query.

Comment: Doesn't GetProcessIoCounters() give you all IO operations including network?

Comment: This gives you disk i/o, network i/o and others, like serial i/o

Answer (score 4):

[WMI](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa394582(VS.85).aspx) can do it, as long as you periodically snapshot it to get differential stats for some "recent" slice of time.  [This post](http://yong321.freeshell.org/freeware/pio.html#windows) presents a peculiarly mixed solution, with [VBScript](http://yong321.freeshell.org/freeware/pio_vbs.txt) reading the info from WMI and [Perl](http://yong321.freeshell.org/freeware/topioWin_pl.txt) continually presenting the information in a Windows console.  Despite the strange language mix, I think it stands as a good example of how to get at the kind of information you require (it should be quite possible to recode all of it in C++, of course).

Comment: Again, the total all IO operations (the same as GetProcessIoCounters())