# Per Process disk read/write statistics in Mac OS X

Tags: performance, macos, statistics, disk

How do I get programatically per process disk i/o statistics in Mac OS X. In 'Activity Monitor' application or in 'top' command we can only get whole system disk i/o statistics.
For reference [Similar question asked for PC.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639903/programmatically-getting-per-process-disk-io-statistics-on-windows)

Comment: @Anoop This is part of a processor monitoring tool, not for hacking

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Use `iotop` (as root), for example:

```
iotop -C 3 10
```

But the best way (for me) is:

```
sudo fs_usage -f filesys
```

Comment: very handy. iotop only showed me that mds and mdworker were hammering my disk. fs_usage showed the zillions of files in Mail.app that it was indexing, so pointed me in the right direction as to what the issue was.

Comment: Note that with El Capitan, it doesn't work, as `iotop` relies on `dtrace`. And El Capitan disables `dtrace` with the rootless (SIP) mode.

Comment: This is broken on Sierra, too.

Answer (score 4):

Since there isn't an answer here about how to do this programatically, here's some more info. You can get some info out of libproc if you can use C/C++/ObjectiveC++. The function `proc_pid_rusage` gives you a bunch of resource info for a given process, but the ones related to your question are:

```
struct rusage_info_v3 {
    ...
    uint64_t ri_diskio_bytesread;
    uint64_t ri_diskio_byteswritten;
    ...
};
```

Sample code:

```
pid_t pid = 10000;
rusage_info_current rusage;
if (proc_pid_rusage(pid, RUSAGE_INFO_CURRENT, (void **)&rusage) == 0)
{
    cout << rusage.ri_diskio_bytesread << endl;
    cout << rusage.ri_diskio_byteswritten << endl;
}
```

See `<libproc.h>` and `<sys/resource.h>` for more info.

Comment: but proc_pid_rusage always fail with -1, and errno is 22.

Answer (score 3):

Since OP specifically asked for disk I/O statistics I'd recommend

```
sudo fs_usage -f diskio
```

which focuses only on read/write events, contrary to `-f filesys` as mentioned in the accepted answer. (Don't know if the `diskio` option wasn't available back then.)

Answer (score 2):

Activity Monitor shows per process I/O statistics in the "disk" tab (perhaps its new since this question was asked).[image] See "Bytes Written" and "Bytes Read" columns.

Comment: These are aggregate counts over the lifespan of the process, and do not show periodic/current statistics like top or iotop. I don't know why Apple thinks these stats are useful. People want `iotop` like functionality.

Comment: Right, I end up just ordering by 'bytes written' etc. and manually tracking deltas with my eyes.  Not programmatic at all sadly.

Comment: Do you know how these aggregate counts are made? Is it just by constantly summing up all the small disk writes/reads? Can I access those aggregate figures with Terminal?

Comment: @theferrit32 Why would you think aggregate counts aren't useful? If "People" want iotop output, they can use iotop.

Answer (score 1):

I found [iStat Menus](https://bjango.com/mac/istatmenus/), which sits in the menu bar. Only shows the top 5 disk read/write users (and I'm not sure if it's the sum, but it doesn't sort).