# Getting information about process in Swift

Tags: swift, process, usage-statistics

I am trying to get some data about a process in Swift.
I am using this code as a starting point:

```
pid_t pid = 10000;
rusage_info_current rusage;
if (proc_pid_rusage(pid, RUSAGE_INFO_CURRENT, (void **)&rusage) == 0)
{
    cout << rusage.ri_diskio_bytesread << endl;
    cout << rusage.ri_diskio_byteswritten << endl;
}
```

taken from [Per Process disk read/write statistics in Mac OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15786618/per-process-disk-read-write-statistics-in-mac-os-x/16451377).

However, I have trouble converting the code above to Swift:

```
var usage = rusage_info_v3()     
if proc_pid_rusage(100, RUSAGE_INFO_CURRENT, &usage) == 0
{
    Swift.print("Success")
}
```

The function prod_pid_rusage expects a parameter of type rusage_info_t?, but I can not instantiate an instance of that type.
Is it possible to use the function in Swift?

Regards,
Sascha

Comment: instead of allocating it on the stack, are you able to allocate one on the heap (e.g. `
var usage = UnsafeMutablePointer<rusage_info_t>.allocate(capacity: 1)`)

Comment: No, unfortunately I can not: "Cannot pass immutable value of type 'rusage_info_t?' as inout argument"

Comment: Try roc_pid_rusage(100, RUSAGE_INFO_CURRENT, &usage!)

Comment: Does not work either.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

As in C you have to take the address of a `rusage_info_current`
variable and cast it to the type expected by `proc_pid_rusage()`.
In Swift this is done using  `withUnsafeMutablePointer()`
and `withMemoryRebound()`:

```
let pid = getpid()
var usage = rusage_info_current()

let result = withUnsafeMutablePointer(to: &usage) {
    $0.withMemoryRebound(to: rusage_info_t?.self, capacity: 1) {
        proc_pid_rusage(pid, RUSAGE_INFO_CURRENT, $0)
    }
}
if result == 0 {
    print(usage.ri_diskio_bytesread)
    // ...
}
```

You have to add

```
#include <libproc.h>
```

to the bridging header file to make it compile.