# Input/output operations per second of an application in Windows

Tags: c++, windows, winapi

I need the Input/output operations per second information of an application. Is there a way to monitor Input/output operations per second of an application ?

Answer (score 1):

[Programmatically getting per-process disk io statistics on Windows?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1639903/programmatically-getting-per-process-disk-io-statistics-on-windows) seems to answer this question.

You can call [GetProcessIoCounters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683218(VS.85).aspx) to get overall disk I/O data per process - you'll need to keep track of deltas and converting to time-based rate yourself.

This API will tell you total number of I/O operations as well as total bytes.

Comment: If you find an exact duplicate you should vote to close as a duplicate, rather than make a new answer.